# Javascript code does not work when getting the value from button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I press a button I get the value of the 1st button. I want the value of the button that was pressed.

JavaScript

```
function GetHadess() {
        var title = $(".myButtonn").val();
        alert(title);    
}
```

The value of the button that was pressed should be shown in alert, but here value of the 1st button is shown.

HTML code

```
<tbody id="tbl">
<tr><td><input class="myButtonn" type="submit" name="title1" value=" bbb " onclick="GetHadess()"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input class="myButtonn" type="submit" name="title1" value=" bb " onclick="GetHadess()"></td></tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: pass this to the function and use this as context to get the value. or create an event hanadler

Comment: "If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's how [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) then return here and do the same with the tick/checkmark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. *Welcome to Stack! "*

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass `this` context to the function so that it will know which button clicked,like below:-

```js
function GetHadess(element) {
  var title = $(element).val();
  alert(title);    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody id="tbl">
  <tr>
    <td><input class="myButtonn" type="submit" name="title1" value=" bbb " onclick="GetHadess(this)">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="myButtonn" type="submit" name="title1" value=" bb " onclick="GetHadess(this)">
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Use this context to tell which is the click button

```js
$('.myButtonn').click(function() {

  alert($(this).val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="tbl">
    <tr>
      <td><input class="myButtonn" type="submit" name="title1" value=" bbb " onclick="GetHadess()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="myButtonn" type="submit" name="title1" value=" bb " onclick="GetHadess()"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
<tbody id="tbl">
<tr><td><input class="myButtonn" type="submit" name="title1" value=" bbb " onclick="GetHadess(this)"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input class="myButtonn" type="submit" name="title1" value=" bb " onclick="GetHadess(this)"></td></tr>
</tbody>


function GetHadess(this) {
        var title = this.val();
        alert(title);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting value using class, Pass event in the function and access value using event.target.value.

```js
function GetHadess(e) {
        console.log(e.target.value);
        alert(e.target.value);    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody id="tbl">
<tr><td><input class="myButtonn" type="submit" name="title1" value=" bbb " onclick="GetHadess(event)"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input class="myButtonn" type="submit" name="title1" value=" bb " onclick="GetHadess(event)"></td></tr>
</tbody>
```